# MBProgressHUD not working with ARC

Tags: iphone, ios, automatic-ref-counting

Usually I write programs without the ARC but I have inherited an application that was written by someone else who used ARC. I need to add MBProgressHUD to it, but anytime I do I get all kinds of release build errors. My question is, is there an alternative to MBProgressHUD or any way to get it to work with ARC?

Comment: What errors are you getting? `MBProgressHUD` works perfectly for me under ARC just by passing the `-fno-objc-arc` compiler flag to `MBProgressHUD.m`.

Comment: @ChriseDoble How did you implement it, I am having problems getting it to work. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8290717/storyboard-ios-mbprogresshud

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just turn off ARC for MBProgressHUD .h/.m [in Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646052/how-can-i-disable-arc-for-a-single-file-in-a-project). Even though the developer has not contributed to the project recently, I imagine most libraries like this will **not** see ARC-compatibility in future.