# Storyboard iOS MBProgressHUD

Tags: iphone, ios, storyboard

I am trying to setup MBProgressHUD on a project that uses storyboards, I am getting the errors below when ever I try to compile it. I then get no popup when I click on my button to call this. Any ideas on what i can do to fix this?

Code:

```
    HUD = self.navigationController.view;
    [self.navigationController.view addSubview:HUD];

    HUD.delegate = self;
    HUD.labelText = @"Loading";

    [HUD showWhileExecuting:@selector(myTask) onTarget:self withObject:nil animated:YES];
```

Errors:

> DetailViewController.m:162:24:{162:24-162:28}: warning: passing
>   'DetailViewController *const __strong' to parameter of incompatible
>   type 'id' [3]
>
> DetailViewController.m: warning: Semantic Issue: Incompatible pointer
>   types assigning to 'MBProgressHUD *__strong' from 'UIView *'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't understand why you're assigning a `UIView` to (what I'm assuming is) an `MBProgressHUD` variable on the first line of your example. The following shows typical usage of `MBProgressHUD`—this works for me under ARC (referencing your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8290437/mbprogresshud-not-working-with-arc)):

```
self.HUD = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithView:self.navigationController.view];
[self.navigationController.view addSubview:self.HUD];
[self.HUD setDelegate:self];
[self.HUD setLabelText:@"Loading"];
[self.HUD showWhileExecuting:@selector(myTask) onTarget:self withObject:nil animated:YES];
```